# A simple connected graph on 100 vertices has 102 edges. Show that.....................

Tags: graph-theory

A simple connected graph on 100 vertices has 102 edges. Show that the graph contains three
pairwise different cycles. (Two cycles are different if their edge sets are not the same.)

How to solve this question ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, a spanning tree has $99$ edges ...

Comment: What can we conclude from it?

Comment: What happens when you add an edge to a tree?

Comment: We can create at most 1 cycle

Comment: But you have to add $3$ edges to the spanning tree to get to $102$

Comment: Aha thank you , I see